# How to find a derivative implicitly?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

In class my professor gave u s the function $\sin{(xy)} = x^{2} + y^{2} + z^{2}$ and asked us to find $\frac{\partial x}{\partial y}.$ For this he said implicit differentiation was needed and wrote the following: $$ \cos{(xy)} \cdot x \frac{\partial x}{\partial y} = 2x \frac{\partial x}{\partial y} + 2y + 0, $$ $$ x \cos{(xy)} \frac{\partial x}{\partial y} - 2x \frac{\partial x}{\partial y} = 2y, $$ $$ \frac{\partial x}{\partial y} [ x \cos{(xy)}  - 2x ] = 2y, $$ $$ \frac{\partial x}{\partial y} = \frac{2y}{x \cos{(xy)}  - 2x}. $$ My problem is that I don't understand what he did to get from the given function to $ \cos{(xy)} \cdot x \frac{\partial x}{\partial y} = 2x \frac{\partial x}{\partial y} + 2y + 0,$ because I try to differentiate the function on both sides, but I don't get this equation. Can somebody please explain?

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{\partial (sin(xy))}{\partial y} = cos(xy) *\frac{\partial (xy)}{\partial y}= cos(xy)*(\frac{\partial x}{\partial y}y+x)$$

???

Since this question kind of assumes x is a function of y to derive the RHS, then the derivation on the left is incorrect.

Comment: I was thinking the same, $x$ is a function of $y$ and $z$ is not, but still don't get it. If I differentiate $\sin{(xy)}$ with these assumptions I get $\cos{(xy)} [\frac{\partial x}{\partial y} y + x]$, since the $xy$ would be a product of functions that depend on $y$.

Comment: I'm sorry for being a headache but I don't understand how you are differentiating $\frac{\partial (xy)}{\partial y}$. If we agree that $x$ is a function of $y$, then this would be the derivative of a product of functions since **both** $x$ and $y$ depend on $y$. Hence its derivative would be, to the best of my understanding, $\frac{\partial x}{\partial y} y + x$.

Comment: Huh you're right, didn't actually think about it. I'd email your prof and ask.